# Rabbitmq File Descriptor Limit

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

Rabbitmq documentation says that we need to do some configuration before we use it on production. One of the configuration is about maximum open file number (which is an OS parameter).

Rabbitmq server we use is running on Ubuntu 16.04 and according to resources I found on web, I updated the number of open files as 500k. When I check it from command line, I get the following output:

```
root@madeleine:~# ulimit -n
500000
```

However when I look at the rabbitmq server status, I see another number.

```
root@madeleine:~# rabbitmqctl status | grep 'file_descriptors' -A 4
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,924},
      {total_used,19},
      {sockets_limit,829},
      {sockets_used,10}]},
```

It seems like, I managed to increase the limit on OS side, but rabbitmq still thinks that total limit of file descriptors is 924.

What might be causing this problem?

Comment: That depends entirely on how you're running RabbitMQ, and how you configured the open file limit.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I am using a config file to run Rabbitmq. Its content is here, can you take a look at it?

[{rabbit, [{vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.4},{disk_free_limit, {mem_relative, 2.0}}]}].

Comment: Which OS are you using? do you use systemd?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and yes I am using systemd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to look at this [page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html#linux-max-open-files-limit-options-other-linux)

Apparently, this operation depends on the OS version. If you have a **systemd**, you should do the following in */etc/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service.d/limits.conf* file:

*Notice that this service configuration might be somewhere else according to the operating system you are using. You can use the following command to find where this service configuration is located and update that file.*

```
find / -name "*rabbitmq-server.service*"
```

**[Service]**

**LimitNOFILE=300000**

On the other hand, if you do not have the systemd folder, you should try this in your *rabbitmq-env.conf* file:

**ulimit -S -n 4096**

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 **/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service** add **LimitNOFILE** under [Service] block works

Comment: @cwhsu, this is really bad advice as that file can be overwritten by package updates.

Comment: The proper way to edit systemd service is `sudo systemctl edit rabbitmq-server.service` - this will figure out what is the correct location for your override file and open it in your preferred editor. Then you can just add the `[Service]` block as suggested, save and quit. systemctl will then also reload the configuration for you.

Comment: Another way (ubuntu 16.04). After installation there is no folder `/etc/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service.d`. Just create it and put file `limits.conf`in that folder. In file add the `[Service]` block as in answer. Then in console `sudo service rabbitmq-server restart` for restart and `sudo rabbitmqctl status` for check.

Answer (score 2):

Increase / Set maximum number of open files

***sudo sysctl -w fs.file-max=65536***
These limits are defined in /etc/security/limits.conf

***sudo nano /etc/security/limits.conf***
and set

soft nofile 65536
hard nofile 65536
Per user settings for rabbitmq process can also be set in 
/etc/default/rabbitmq-server

***sudo nano /etc/default/rabbitmq-server***
and set

ulimit -n 65536
Then reboot the server for changes to take effect.

Comment: These steps seems like working. ulimit -n now returns 65536 but still, in rabbitmqctl status command's output, file_descriptors values are not increased.